# Creating dynamic database to which I can send data from android device

Tags: android, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-sql

Simple example what I am trying to do.

I want to have database with one variable. I want to increase value of this variable from my android device.

Lets say I have button in my android application. When I click on it I want increase value of variable in database by let's say one.

I was considering using Google Cloud SQL Storage but I think there should be easier way to do that.

Have anyone faced problem like this?

What is the best solution for this problem?

Comment: you want to communicate with a remote db and update its values accordingly?  need to look at creating a web service that will cross-communicate for you.

Comment: Connecting to a database directly from an android application has a lot of security issues. Consider looking at solutions like Firebase which are designed to make this simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned, [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/) is a good solution. There is also [Google Cloud Datastore](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/datastore-api-tutorial), which is somewhat more unwieldy than Firebase.

On a related note, if having a full app back-end seems overkill you might want to take a look at the alpha preview of [Google Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/), which are cloud-hosted Javascript functions you can invoke with a simple HTTP trigger.